# Passing a methods arguments to its parent classes constructor (Flask -- ModelView.as_view())

Tags: python, flask

This is more of a general Python question than a Flask question.

This snippet of code comes from https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/views.py#L18.

```
@classmethod
def as_view(cls, name, *class_args, **class_kwargs):
    """Converts the class into an actual view function that can be used
    with the routing system.  Internally this generates a function on the
    fly which will instantiate the :class:`View` on each request and call
    the :meth:`dispatch_request` method on it.

    The arguments passed to :meth:`as_view` are forwarded to the
    constructor of the class.
    """
    def view(*args, **kwargs):
        self = view.view_class(*class_args, **class_kwargs)
        return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)

    if cls.decorators:
        view.__name__ = name
        view.__module__ = cls.__module__
        for decorator in cls.decorators:
            view = decorator(view)

    # we attach the view class to the view function for two reasons:
    # first of all it allows us to easily figure out what class-based
    # view this thing came from, secondly it's also used for instantiating
    # the view class so you can actually replace it with something else
    # for testing purposes and debugging.
    view.view_class = cls
    view.__name__ = name
    view.__doc__ = cls.__doc__
    view.__module__ = cls.__module__
    view.methods = cls.methods
    return view
```

Can somebody explain to me how exactly this `as_view()` function forwards its arguments to the constructor of the `View` class as it says it does in the method comment?

If not a direct explanation, maybe a shove in the right direction about specifically what I need to learn about Python-wise to better understand what is going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the key one:

```
self = view.view_class(*class_args, **class_kwargs)
```

It's taking the arguments passed to `as_view` and using them to create an instance of `view` with those arguments.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, although I'm not quite understanding how we can call (for example) `view.view_class = cls` when `view` is a function.  Shouldn't we have to pass it params, or at least use parentheses like `view()`.view_class?

Comment: Functions are objects just like everything else in Python, and they can have attributes attached to them. This is done after the function definition: `view.view_class = cls`. In other words, the view function is given an attribute `view_class` which is the containing class, so calling this will instantiate that class.

Comment: So (in this case) as soon as we call `view.` it will execute the method and be assigned whatever `self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)` returns, and then we access `view_class` on that?

Comment: No. `view` is called from the route matcher when a user requests that URL. By this time `as_view` has already set up `view.view_class`. So at that point `view` initializes the class, assigns it to `self`, then calls *that instance's* `dispatch_request` which does the actual work of the view (ie talking to the database, rendering the template, creating the output), then returns it to the user.